# How do I manage PCs with vPro?

Tags: remote-access, intel

I ordered some new PCs with Intel vPro enabled on them, but now that I have them I'm not sure how to use it.

I found some old websites about using Altiris and Microsoft SMS but those are expensive and really meant for large organizations. Does anyone know of a free or cheap way to use vPro?

Comment: What did you end up using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intel has a list of free tools at the below link:

http://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-1171

Another option is [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/%22Spiceworks%22), a free network monitoring/help desk/PC inventory tool.  An Intel AMT plugin available to allow remote access, device sharing, and power on/off from within Spiceworks.

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: 11 years past: the current Intel's own freely available vPro/AMT solution is EMA: [EMA/AMT user forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-vPro-Platform/bd-p/vpro-platform), [temporary snag announce--download pulled out because bug](https://community.intel.com/t5/f/m/m-p/1383646), [(non)-download link and other documents](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/search.html?ws=text#q="EMA%29"&f:@tabfilter=[Downloads]).

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_vPro#Remote-Management_Features):

> VNC-based KVM Remote Control
>
> In vPro 6.0 PCs with embedded Intel graphics, Intel AMT embeds a proprietary VNC Server, so you can connect out-of-band using dedicated VNC-compatible Viewer technology, and have full KVM (Keyboard, Video, Mouse) capability throughout the power cycle - including uninterrupted control of the desktop when an operating system loads. Clients such as VNC Viewer Plus from RealVNC also >provide additional functionality that might make it easier to perform (and watch) certain Intel AMT operations, such as powering >the computer off and on, configuring the BIOS, and mounting a remote image (IDER).

Have you tried using a VNC Viewer to connect to these machines?

- [RealVNC](http://realvnc.com/)
- [UltraVNC](http://ultravnc.com/)
- [TightVNC](http://tightvnc.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Every Intel AMT enabled PC has a web server running on port 16992 and/or 16993 (https).

Just point your web browser to:

```
 http://'Intel-AMT-enabled-host':16992
```

or

```
 https://'Intel-AMT-enabled-host':16993
```

Comment: What about the other ports Intel vPro 16992-16995, 5900, 623, 664 mentioned here?  https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/guides/scs-deployment-guide.pdf - And I also read that port 9971 is used for hello messages too

Answer (score 2):

**2018 Update:**

[UltraVNC](http://ultravnc.com/) now redirects to [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/). The RealVNC product you need is the [Viewer Plus](https://www.realvnc.com/en/products/viewerplus/) - the standard (and free client) does not do KVM over IP.

There is no information on [TightVNC](http://tightvnc.com/)'s site regarding capacity to access the VNC server running inside a vPro chip.

**Other options are**:

- [MeshCommander](http://www.meshcommander.com/meshcommander) (open source). Allows for [controlling the Intel AMT and LMS, and also for KVM over IP](https://prajwaldesai.com/control-remote-computers-using-intel-amt/), so you can watch the boot screen and set RAID or BIOS options (like RealVNC does)
- [Dameware](https://www.dameware.com/features/intel-vpro-remote-control-management) (paid)
- Intel's own free Management Command Tool (MDTK), which has been replaced by MeshCommander, but still might be [required to use TLS with MeshCommander](https://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2014/12/set-up-intel-amt-for-remote-kvm/). Note that MeshCommander has released several fixes on TLS and MDTK might no longer be needed.
- As far as I understood this option, you can [setup an intermediate Ubuntu box to use as a KVM over IP device into the machine you actually want to control](http://jefflane.org/v2/technology/setting-up-intel-amt-to-act-as-a-remote-kvm-in-linux/) (clumsy)